# Autopopulating a sign up form with params from pre-registration form not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters, auto-populate

so I'm trying to build a sign-up process just like [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com) has. Meaning, there's a pre-sign up form which leads to full form with autopopulated fields from the first form. I'm trying to create this using `:value => @name` in the final form, but it's not working and I just can't figure out why.

Here's my code, simplified:

**First form, controller: public_controller, action: index (root_path)**

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "users", :action => "register"})%>
  <input name="user[name]" type="text" />
  <input name="user[email]" type="text"/>
  <input name="user[password]" type="password"/>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign Up!" />
```

**Second form, controller: users_controller, action: register (/signup)**

```
 <%= form_for(:user, :url => { :controller => 'users', :action => 'create' }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name,  :value => @name %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :value => @email %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :value => @password %>
    <input name="commit" type="submit"
           value="Sign Up!" />
    <% end %>
```

**Users_controller**

```
def register
  @name     = params[:name]
  @email    = params[:email]
  @password = params[:password]
end
```

**The params are passing to the final form page (/signup)**

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"R3wVNHvqpDBi1Lg69lwKu4NeQGjA12oV/Aytw38OeHc=",           "user"=>{"name"=>"Stackoverflow", "email"=>"stack@stackstack.com", "password"=>"stacker",   "password_confirmation"=>"stacker"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up!", "search"=>"", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"register"}

But they are not autopopulating the final form's fields.

I've also tried using `:input_html => { :value => @name }` with `params[:name]`, but it has no effect, and the input's value simply turns to value="nil".

I just can't think of anything else to try from here. Any ideas? Thanks in advance! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It should be working, have you checked the `params` hash in your `register` action?

Comment: Yeah, it was okay. I finally actually got it working by thrashing the variables from `register` action and just going `:value => params[:user][:name] and params[:user][:email]` on the final form. No idea why it didn't work the other way around, but I guess this does the same job. Thanks a lot for looking at it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tiny oversight on the controller?
shouldn't it be

```
def register
  @name     = params[:user][:name]
  @email    = params[:user][:email]
  @password = params[:user][:password]
end
```

you kinda figured it out in the end though.